# Add key value to parent subelement if child has specific key:value

Tags: json, parent-child, jq

I'm trying to understand what's the best way to add a json element to child's parent
if that child contains a specific key:value and finally print the entire json using jq
I try to explain better with an example.
The input json is:

```
{
  "family": {
    "surname": "Smith"
  },
  "components": [
    {
      "name": "John",
      "details": {
        "hair": "brown",
        "eyes": "brown",
        "age": "56"
      },
      "role": "father"
    },
    {
      "name": "Mary",
      "details": {
        "hair": "blonde",
        "eyes": "green",
        "age": "45"
      },
      "role": "mother"
    },
    {
      "name": "George",
      "details": {
        "hair": "blonde",
        "eyes": "brown",
        "age": "25"
      },
      "role": "child"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to add:
"description": "5 years less than 30"
at the same level of "details" if "age" is equal to "25" and then print the result:

```
{
  "family": {
    "surname": "Smith"
  },
  "components": [
    {
      "name": "John",
      "details": {
        "hair": "brown",
        "eyes": "brown",
        "age": "56"
      },
      "role": "father"
    },
    {
      "name": "Mary",
      "details": {
        "hair": "blonde",
        "eyes": "green",
        "age": "45"
      },
      "role": "mother"
    },
    {
      "name": "George",
      "details": {
        "hair": "blonde",
        "eyes": "brown",
        "age": "25"
      },
      "role": "child",
      "description": "5 years less than 30"
    }
  ]
}
```

The only solution I've found was to apply the update but printing only the "components" content;
then I've removed from the JSON and finally inserted the modified "components" content previously saved, in this way:

```
cat sample.json | jq -c ' .components[] | select(.details.age=="25") |= . + {description: "5 years less than 30" } ' > /tmp/saved-components.tmp
cat sample.json | jq --slurpfile savedcomponents /tmp/saved-components.tmp 'del(.components) | . + { components: [ $savedcomponents ] }'
```

I don't think it's the best way to solve these kind of problems, so I'd like to know what is
the right "jq approach".
I forgot to say: I prefer to use jq only, not other tools

Than you

Marco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a straightforward ("no magic") and efficient solution:

```
.components |= 
  map(if .details.age=="25" then .description = "5 years less than 30" else . end)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can select the object matching the condition and append to that object. Something like below. The key is to use `+=` the modification assignment to not lose the other objects

```
(.components[] | select(.details.age == "25")) += { "description": "5 years less than 30" }
```

<sup>[jqplay - Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/_m0fNNG-8x)</sup>

Comment: Thank you, your and @peak solutions works very well; I'd like to set both to accepted solution, but I don't know how to do. I tried to iterate your solution, in this way: `cat sample.json | jq '(.components[] | select(.details.age == "25")) += { "description": "5 years less than 30" }' | jq '(.components[] | select(.details.age == "25")) += { "description": "under 30" }'` and I expected to see two description keys, but I see only the last update. Is it a jq feature, that doesn't permit duplicate keys, or is the "+=" operation ?

Comment: jq allows duplicate keys to be specified but normally ignores all but the last. ("Normally" because it's not true when the "streaming parser" (enabled by --stream) is in effect.)